# Rails - Multiple photos with paperclip...what's wrong with this idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm currently using paperclip and imagemagick to upload a single photo for my articles. I've been looking around at ways to add multiple photos. I don't need unlimited photos, in fact I would like to limit it to 8 per article. So that got me thinking, what's wrong with simply having 8 separate attachments? Yes, it means having 8 separate methods, 8 separate lines in the routing table, etc...but so what? I have a very low volume website, so other than bloated code, is there any reason not to do this? I've tested it out with 2 photos and it seems to work great. In fact, it seems to make things easier, because you don't need to consider the 'id' of a particular photo to make it appear at a particular place in the article.

For what it's worth, each photo has a route that looks like this:

```
 get 'article/:id/remove_photo', to: 'articles#remove_photo', as: 'remove_article_photo'
```

and a statement in my model looks like this:

```
has_attached_file :photo , :styles => { :small => '200>', :medium => '400>', :large => '600>' }
 validates_attachment :photo, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
  validates_attachment :photo, :less_than => 1.megabytes
```

There would need to be a separate method for deleting each photo in the controller:

```
def remove_photo 
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@article.photo = nil
@article.save
redirect_to @article
end
```

Yes, its a lot of code, but it's also REALLY easy to understand. And I'm dumber than a donkey, so that's helpful. :D
Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the best way for you to learn why it's not the best strategy would be for you to go and actually implement it -- I have a feeling you'd learn why pretty quick! To actually answer your question, though, the main flaws with your solution are:

- Increased maintenance cost -- suppose you want to support a new filetype for your images. You'd need to change it in eight places, not just one. (This could be mitigated by extracting that big ol' config hash into a constant or configuration file, which is a valid strategy for cutting down on repeated, static data).
- An inability to deal with your list-like data in a list-like fashion -- since your photos now live in `photo1`, `photo2`, `photo3`, etc., how would you quickly tell me how many photos an article has on it? How could you sort the photos by their title?
- Icky code -- if you're the only developer, maybe this doesn't matter now... but eventually even you will look back at it and groan!

Formally, what you're proposing is known as [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). In some cases, it's justified -- denormalized data is often quicker to access, and can provide certain constraints more easily (like how you want to only allow eight photos per article).

If you were dealing with a more hash-like data set, it could definitely make sense -- for example, `side_photo` vs `main_photo` vs `author_photo`. Since your photos are simply a list, though, I'd recommend creating a Photo model in your database, and attach the paperclip reference to that model (not Article).

Anyway, your data model is up to you! If you do end up denormalizing the columns, let me leave you with a bit of metaprogramming that will make your life easier:

```
def remove_photo
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.send("photo#{params[:photo_id].to_i}=", nil)
  @article.save
  redirect_to @article
end
```

The `send` method in Ruby invokes a method on an object dynamically, which I used above to sub in the `photo_id` parameter. So you would just need one route, matching `DELETE articles/:id/photos/:photo_id`, and that action to handle all of your photoX columns.

Comment: Robert, thank your such an in depth answer! Excellent guidance.